# Implement callable cloud functions in Firebase client app

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have recently discovered the [Firebase callable functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) which allows me to call HTTPS trigger like function from the client side (and with auth() support).

I struggle to implement this new feature in my already existing Firebase web-client application.

I have some cloud functions running, among them are some HTTPS functions I would like to transform into an HTTPS callable function (with [functions.https.onCall](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.https?authuser=0#.onCall)).

The documentation indicates:

```
Set up your client development environment
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.0/firebase-functions.js"></script>
```

And my code is:

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: '....',
  authDomain: '....',
  databaseURL: '....',
  projectId: '....',
  storageBucket: '....',
  messagingSenderId: '....',
});

const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
const auth = firebaseApp.auth();
const functions = firebaseApp.functions();

export { db, auth, functions };
```

When I run my app, I got the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: firebaseApp.functions is not a function
```

I have tried `yarn add firebase-functions` and then `import 'firebase-functions` but then the app requires `firebase-admin`. I am affraid it is too much for a client-app so I might go in the wrong direction.

Can someone help me with this issue?
(!) This issue is **NOT** about the server-side Firebase SDK for Cloud Functions (Node JS). It is about calling Cloud functions directly from a Firebase web app.
Thank you!

**UPDATE:**
Thanks to @Andrew's post, this solves my issue:

My configuration

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import '@firebase/functions';
import firestoreConfig from '@/config/firestore';

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firestoreConfig /* The JSON configuration from my Firebase project */);

const db = firebaseApp.firestore();
const auth = firebaseApp.auth();
const functions = firebaseApp.functions();

export { db, auth, functions };
```

Using the configuration:

```
import { db, functions } from '@/database/firestoreInit';

export default {
  addMessage(text) {
    const addMessage = functions.httpsCallable('addMessage');
    return addMessage({ text }).then(result => result);
  },
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just ran into this same problem myself and solved it by installing and importing the *@firebase/functions* npm package. I found the solution on github here: 
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/master/packages/functions/README.md

From the README on github:

**ES Modules**

```
import firebase from '@firebase/app';
import '@firebase/functions'
// Do stuff w/ `firebase` and `firebase.functions`
```

**CommonJS Modules**

```
const firebase = require('@firebase/app').default;
require('@firebase/functions');

// Do stuff with `firebase` and `firebase.functions`
```

Hope that helps! The actual documentation is not very clear about having to do this in order to call the functions.

Comment: Thank you @Andrew, you made my day :) This is exactly what I missed

Answer (score 1):

About [@firebase/functions](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/master/packages/functions/README.md):

> This package is not intended for direct usage, and should only be used via the officially supported firebase package.

This worked for me:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'; // Typescript
// import firebase from 'firebase/app'; // JS
import 'firebase/functions';

const myCallableFunc = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('myCallableFunc');
```

I don't know about importing `firebase-functions` with a CDN but if you're using npm then you don't need the `firebase-functions` package, just installing `firebase` will do.

Comment: for me, the key was the first import in your answer been banging my head fro 3 days

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps mentioned here. [Firebase cloud functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started)

I think there is nothing like `firebaseApp.functions`.

Comment: Hi, I have followed the tutorial from https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#set_up_your_client_development_environment. You can see there are two parts. The first one is <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.12.0/firebase-functions.js"></script> and the second part is firebase.initializeApp({...}) and var functions = firebase.functions();

As I do not want to use <script> tags, I have tried to import 'firebase-functions', without success.