# Expo and firebase cloud functions

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-functions, expo

**Edit:** 
I Solved the Problem by changing `import '@firebase/functions'` to `import 'firebase/functions'`

---

I'm creating an app using expo and firebase.
I trying to add Cloud functions to be callable in my app.

My code is the following in my `FirebaseApi.js`

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase'
import '@firebase/functions'

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "...",
  authDomain: "...",
  databaseURL: "...",
  projectId: "...",
  storageBucket: "...",
  messagingSenderId: "..."
}



export default class Firebase {
  static auth;
  static database;
  static storage;
  static functions;
  static EmailAuthProvider;

  static init() {
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

    Firebase.auth = firebase.auth();
    Firebase.auth.setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL);

    Firebase.EmailAuthProvider = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider;

    Firebase.database = firebase.database();

    Firebase.storage = firebase.storage();

    Firebase.functions = firebase.functions();
  }
}
```

First i encountered the error that firebase.functions() is undefiend, which lead me to the following article on here: [Implement callable cloud functions in Firebase client app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49487770/implement-callable-cloud-functions-in-firebase-client-app?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

But this solution doesn't seem to work with firebase.
I did call `npm install --save @firebase/functions` and in my package.js @firebase/functions is insalled.

But when trying to build the app it states

```
Unable to resolve @firebase/functions" from ".//js/firebase/firebaseAPI.js"
```

Am i doing something wrong, or is there maybe a problem using Firebase Cloud functions with expo?

Comment: I don't get it, is your app a backend or a client?

Comment: its a callable cloud function. the problem is when implemention the calling on the app side.

Comment: If you solve your own problem, you can answer it too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution in the link was almost right.
For me, I needed to ditch the `@`.

So, instead of

```
import '@firebase/functions'
```

you need

```
import 'firebase/functions'
```